# Google Tag Manager Causing Google Page Speed Issues

Tags: google-tag-manager, pagespeed-insights

[enter image description here][1]
page speed fall on mobile with GTM tag manager
LCP is clear
CLS is clear
FID is clear
all clear but page speed is bellow 90%
is there any update on google regarding this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FnRl.png